# Is the phrase "Those one track minds" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, songs

There is an interesting grammatical construction in the song [Shout by Tears For Fears](https://youtu.be/Ye7FKc1JQe4?t=68).

> They really really ought to know
>
> **Those one track minds**
>
> That took you for a working boy
>
> Kiss them goodbye

I'm interested in the phrase "**Those one track minds**" which for me sounds incorrect. It feels like there should be "That" instead of "Those". First, I though that they broke the rules because of the rhyme, but "That one tracks minds" would have fitted ok without braking the rhyme.

Is there an explanation of such usage? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: *Those* is correct.  It refers to those people with one-track minds”. Also, you are parsing it as connected to the first line.  It is actually a new thought which connects to the third line.

Comment: _That minds_ is not correct; it must be _that mind_ or _those minds_. The demonstrative determinatives agree with the nouns they qualify in number.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - How do you know they're not all of one mind?

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. I didn't know that "one-track mind" is an idiom.

Comment: @HotLicks I don’t; wouldn’t make a difference if they were, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If the OP used *that* in place of *those*, the meaning changes significantly. The linkage becomes "know that" instead of "those ... minds".

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, obviously in the context here, _those minds_ is the only option. I was talking about grammaticality in general there.

Comment: If a man has a "one-track mind", it means he is primarily interested in one thing. Often said disparagingly by women when the "one thing" is sex. "He's got a one-track mind - a dirt track". This is a British idiom since the 1950s at least. Maybe it is used elsewhere. Dirt track racing was a type of motorcycle racing.

Comment: A non-question. Voting to close.

Comment: There's nothing to proof-read; nothing a matter of opinion; nothing to do with lyric writing.

Comment: @Kris could you please elaborate on why it is off-topic? I've just reread the rules https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and I don't see how it could be related to proofreading. But even if it was somehow related the rule says "unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified". Isn't the source clearly specified?

Comment: @Kris since I'm not a native English speaker I simply didn't know that "one track mind" is an idiom. For me, the phrase "Those one track minds" looked like "Those people track minds" (I thought "track" was a verb here) and I couldn't get why they changed "people" with "one", it looked like they broke grammar rules, that's why I posted it here. I'm not sure if I managed to explain it, at least I tried.

Comment: Ah! So that's it. I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note here that 'minds' is not a verb. It is not like saying *he minds the shop while they're eating* - it is a noun and the object of *to know*. 
*one track* should really be hyphenated because it's an idiomatic compound adjective. *one-track* originates from description of trains (see [this page](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/one-track-mind)) and means that someone/something is repetitive or obsessed with something (i.e. their thoughts always return along the same track to the same ideas). 
Because *one track* is only an adjective, applying to *minds*, you can understand the pronoun *those* by removing this adjective. This way, you get *those minds*, which makes sense - I think the confusion here is just misapplication of the pronoun as applying to 'one' or 'one track'.

Comment: But wait. See my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris your reason that the post is off-topic _Proofreading questions are off-topic **unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**_ means that this is not off-topic; there is a specific source of concern clearly identified in the text ('that' vs. 'those'). Besides which, the question could easily be reworded to ask about any general phrase of that type, rather than that phrase as it is presented in a specific text.

Comment: See the OP's comment above. So that explains everything.

Comment: Yes, he commented that after I answered that it was an idiomatic phrase. I don't understand why you want me to read your comment or his?

Comment: *Those* is irrelevant in the OP's interpretation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86205/discussion-between-joseph-paduch-and-kris).

Comment: My comments so far should have explained things more than adequately.

Comment: You said 'see my comment at OP', and I did - it was not relevant to my answer. You said 'see the OP's comment above', and I did - it demonstrated that the person asking the question had accepted my answer. You said 'those is irrelevant in the OP's interpretation', which I don't agree with, but that still has nothing to do with me. Your comments so far don't quite make sense to me, I'm sorry. "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post." Would you like to clarify anything? Is there anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474249/is-the-phrase-those-one-track-minds-grammatically-correct/474279?noredirect=1#comment1145454_474249

Comment: So there's no issue?

Comment: None. The OP had taken *track* for a verb and *that* in the sense of *which* -- an interpretation wholly different.

Answer (score -1):

Song lyrics like poetry use enjambment In poetry, "enjambment (/ ɛ n ˈ dʒ æ m b m ən t / or / ɛ n ˈ dʒ æ m m ən t /; from the French enjambement) is incomplete syntax at the end of a line; the meaning runs over from one poetic line to the next, without terminal punctuation," Wikipedia. The meaning of the last three lines is "Kiss goodbye those one-track minds that took you for a working boy." But rock music like poetry gains power by slicing things up and moving them around, to both fit the music and provoke the listener. Grammar and syntax don't much obtrude, and likely for the best.  Had Jagger and Richards ran their song by the English Stack Exchange, we would now have (I Can't Get Any) Satisfaction. Would you buy the album?